# For duplicate values in SQL, how do I choose the most recent duplicate value

Tags: sql, oracle, select, greatest-n-per-group

In SQL, I have a table where one column can have duplicate values. How do I select only the most recent duplicate value? The dates are spread out over a month

This is my current code that does not account for the duplicate values (Note: COLUMN1 is the column which has duplicate values)

```
select count(distinct COLUMN1)
from TABLE
where extract(month from DATE_COLUMN) = extract(month from sysdate) - 1
and extract(year from DATE_COLUMN) = extract(year from sysdate)
and COLUMN1 not like '%X';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER() function in a subquery to identify dupes and rank them by a date column. I'm not familiar with oracle but it should be something like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COLUMN1 ORDER BY DATE_COLUMN DESC)
```

Check out this link for an explanation:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function to get the most recent row for each value of `column1`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY column1
                             ORDER BY date_column DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this in a different manner than the ones suggested to me. I bascially created a table that was compromised of two different tables, one with the duplicate values and one without.

```
select DATECOLUMN, count(COLUMN1)
FROM (select COLUMN1, max(DATECOLUMN) "DATECOLUMN"
      from TABLE
      where extract(month from DATECOLUMN) = extract(month from sysdate) - 1
      and extract(year from DATECOLUMN) = extract(year from sysdate)
      group by COLUMN1
      HAVING count(COLUMN1) > 1
      UNION
      select COLUMN1, max(DATECOLUMN) "DATECOLUMN"
      from TABLE 
      where extract(month from DATECOLUMN) = extract(month from sysdate) - 1
      and extract(year from DATECOLUMN) = extract(year from sysdate)
      group by COLUMN1
      HAVING count(COLUMN1) < 2) "NEW_TABLE"
where COLUMN1 not like '%X'
group by DATECOLUMN
order by DATECOLUMN;
```